# Why does boost::make_shared use copy semantics

Tags: c++, boost

I have a small program, whose working I am unable to understand.

```
class A {
     public:
     A() {
        cout<<"Costructor called"<<endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        cout<<"Destructor called"<<endl;
    }
};

A foo() {
    return A();
}


int main() {
    A obj = foo();
    cout<<"A initialized "<<endl;
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr1 = boost::make_shared<A>(foo());
    cout<<"ptr1 initialized "<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Output is:-

```
./a.out
Costructor called
A initialized 
Costructor called
Destructor called
ptr1 initialized 
Destructor called
Destructor called
```

Why is A initialzed and destructed while creating ptr but not while creating obj?

Comment: maybe due to the temporary object returned by `foo()` in `boost::make_shared<A>(foo())`?

Comment: What do you mean *not while creating obj*? The first *Costructor called* is from constructing `obj` and the very last *Destructor called* is from its destruction.

Comment: If you say why you expect that it *wouldn't* be copied then you might get an answer specific to whatever it is you don't understand. I'm not sure whether to answer, "because the copy initialization of `obj` allows copy elision whereas copying an object in and out of a function doesn't", or "because you suppressed the implicit move constructor of `A`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make your class a bit noisier by adding a copy constructor and printing `this` in each of the special members

```
class A {
     public:
     A() {
        cout<<"Constructor called "<< this << endl;
    }

    A(A const&) {
        cout<<"Copy Constructor called "<< this << endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        cout<<"Destructor called "<< this << endl;
    }
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3df3239e33cac51a)

This produces the output

```
Constructor called 0x7fff0ed4883e   // obj is constructed
A initialized 
Constructor called 0x7fff0ed4883f   // return value of foo() is constructed in make_shared call
Copy Constructor called 0x1430c39   // shared_ptr copy constructs A from return value of foo()
Destructor called 0x7fff0ed4883f    // return value of foo() is destroyed
ptr1 initialized 
Destructor called 0x1430c39         // shared_ptr deletes the A it owns
Destructor called 0x7fff0ed4883e    // obj is destroyed
```

Answer (score 1):

`boost::make_shared<A>(foo())` is equivalent to `boost::shared_ptr<A>(new A(foo()))` where `new A(foo())` will call the defaulted copy constructor (or the defaulted move constructor if you're using C++11).

From a higher-order point of view, the return value of `foo()` is created in temporary storage on the stack, while a `shared_ptr` requires a heap-allocated object to be able to free the memory when the reference count goes to 0.

Comment: It's not actually equivalent to that. It's _very similar_ but there will generally be fewer allocations when using `make_shared`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the first case a compiler uses RVO optimization so obj is being constructed inside foo function.

Answer (score 0):

That constructor/destructor pair called between `A initialized` and `ptr1 initialized`

```
./a.out
Costructor called
A initialized 
Costructor called // <- !
Destructor called // <- !
ptr1 initialized 
Destructor called
Destructor called
```

is for temporary instance of type `A` in function `foo()`

```
A foo() {
    return A(); // you are creating the instance (constructor call)
}
```

Since this is a temporary object:

> all temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
>   full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were
>   created

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

It means that destructor call is right after the constructor call.

This behavious is not related or specific to `boost::shared_ptr` or `boost::make_shared()` in any way. Try to replace

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr1 = boost::make_shared<A>(foo());
```

with

```
A ptr1 = foo();
```

and check differences.